# How to show/hide fragment with swipe up/down like soundcloud android app

Tags: android, android-fragments, soundcloud, swipe-gesture

[image: image1][image: image2][image: image3]

I am getting curious to know that how a view can be created like the one shown below . Is this drag and drop or some custom view with gesture detection and animations? What can be a good starting point?

Answer (score 24):

[ViewDragHelper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/ViewDragHelper.html) can be used to achieve this effect. Some good tutorials and samples are:  [dragging-with-viewdraghelper](http://fedepaol.github.io/blog/2014/09/01/dragging-with-viewdraghelper/) and [each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper](http://flavienlaurent.com/blog/2013/08/28/each-navigation-drawer-hides-a-viewdraghelper/) and  [DraggablePanel](https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel) and [AndroidSlidingUpPanel](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)

Answer (score 1):

Checkout BottomSheetDialogFragment from   [new Material](https://material.io/design/components/sheets-bottom.html#modal-bottom-sheet) design, [here](https://medium.com/halcyon-mobile/implementing-googles-refreshed-modal-bottom-sheet-4e76cb5de65b) is a good tutorial on how to do it